# New to Ubuntu. WIFI suspends and laptop hangs

Tags: networking, suspend, 20.04

Being a Newbie to the LINUX world, excitement is filled within me to learn more and more. And, probably the Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my laptop understands me well. LOL!

Guys, my WIFI gets disconnected after 15 to 30 minutes. Assuming, it is AUTO-SUSPEND. As, I am Newbie to Linux commands, I don't know the proper way to fix this issue. Following some resources, I managed to reinstall the WIFI driver, added script for end SUSPEND but later the problem persists.

Here are the resources that I followed;

1. Installing WIFI [ https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new ]
2. Adding a file to end Wifi-suspend [ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n49kukPf8HI&list=LL0Gni-Ntm0QkaxFe8E4BJRw&index=2&t=0s ]

Now, the performance was excellent unless the WIFI connection broke. I then checked the WIFI list, I found none. I, therefore, assumed the WIFI is suspended. I 'Turn Off' the WIFI on Laptop and when I again 'Turn ON', my laptop freezes. None of the Keyboard keys works neither does the mouse. The laptop hangs.

What could be the reason and how to solve this?

Regards,
Dipendra

Comment: Have you find any solutions I am facing same issue when I connect from ethernet it working and when I connect through wifi screen and mouse and keyboard freeze